# Json.Net disable JsonProperty when SerializeObject

Tags: json, json.net

```
public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("student_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use `[JsonProperty("student_name")]` to Deserialize third part json, after that

how can I get `{"Name":"test"}` instead of `{"student_name":"test"}` when call

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);
```

means how to programmly disable `JsonProperty`?

**UPDATE on 2013-12-03:**

write a CustomContractResolver solve the problem

```
public class JsonCustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member,
        MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var res = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        var attrs = member
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true);
        if (attrs.Any())
        {

            if (res.PropertyName != null)
            {
                //UnderlyingName overwrite attribute name
                res.PropertyName = res.UnderlyingName;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by defining custom `JsonConverter`. Here is a sample code:

```
public class StudentConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Student);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object   existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var target = new Student();

        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var std = value as Student;
        if (std == null) return;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
        writer.WriteValue(std.Name);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

After that you need to decorate your `Student` class with the `StudentConverter`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StudentConverter))]
public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("student_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this idea is working, but just for "Student" object, not a general custom converter for all object.